# After creating an object, creating a NEW object alters the fields of the first one

Tags: java

I'm making multiplayer tetris. The TetrisGame class simply runs the game using a loop, while the Tetris class constructor creates a new piece (don't worry about the board2 class, it simply paints the pieces). So here are the two classes:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TetrisGame extends JFrame
{
private board2 myBoard;
private int score;
static Tetris_RafArian tetromino, tet2;
private int speed = 500;
private boolean pause;
private boolean start;

public TetrisGame() throws InterruptedException
{
    super("Tetris");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    keyListener();
    pause=true;
    start=true;
    score=0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(start)
        {
            myBoard = new board2(10, 20);
            add(myBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            tet2 = new Tetris_RafArian(myBoard, 20, 0, 12, 12);
            tetromino = new Tetris_RafArian(myBoard, 4, 0, 12, 6);
            pack();
            runGame();
        }
    score=0;    
    Thread.sleep(1);
    }

}

/**
 * Listens for key action
 */
public void keyListener()
{
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                if (pause && start)
                    tet2.rotateTetro();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                if (pause && start)
                    tetromino.rotateTetro();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                if (tet2.checkWall(0) && pause && start)
                    tet2.move(0);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                if (tetromino.checkWall(0) && pause && start)
                    tetromino.move(0);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                if (tet2.checkWall(1) && pause && start)
                    tet2.move(1);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                if (tetromino.checkWall(1) && pause && start)
                    tetromino.move(1);
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                if (tet2.checkCollision(tet2.tetro()) && pause && start)
                    tet2.fall();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                if (tetromino.checkCollision(tetromino.tetro()) && pause && start)
                    tetromino.fall();
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                if (pause && start)
                    speed = 10;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_P:
                if (pause && start)
                    pause = false;
                else
                    pause = true;
                if (!start)
                    start = true;
            }
            myBoard.repaint();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Runs a single game
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void runGame() throws InterruptedException
{

    //System.out.println(tetromino.checkCollision(tetromino.tetro));
    while(tetromino.checkCollision(tetromino.tetro())||tetromino.tetro()[1][1]!=0)
    {
        while(tetromino.checkCollision(tetromino.tetro()))
        {
            if(pause)
            {
                //tetromino.fall();
                tet2.fall();
                myBoard.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(speed);
            }

        }

        speed = 500;
        int x=0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<20 ; i++)
            if(myBoard.checkRow(i))
            {
                myBoard.removeRow(i);
                score++;
                x++;

            }
        score+=x;
        myBoard.setScore(score);
        tetromino.newTetris();
    }
    start=false;
    myBoard.setEnd(true);
    myBoard.repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException, LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException
{
    new TetrisGame();
}
}
```

---

```
public class Tetris_RafArian
{
private static board2 myBoard;
private static int color, temColor;
private static int alt=0;
private static int xShift, yShift;
private static int xPos, yPos;
private static int[][] tetro, temTetro, shadTetro; // this is public because Game class needs access

public Tetris_RafArian(board2 bd, int x, int y, int tx, int ty)
{
    myBoard=bd;
    xShift=x;
    yShift=y;
    xPos=tx;
    yPos=ty;

    color = (int)(Math.random()*7)+1;
    temColor = (int)(Math.random()*7)+1;

    tetro = chooseRandom(color);
    temTetro = chooseRandom(temColor);

    shadTetro = new int[4][2];
    for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
            shadTetro[i][j]=tetro[i][j];
    setShadTetro();

    myBoard.setTetris(temTetro, temColor, xPos, yPos);
    myBoard.setTetris(tetro, color, xShift, yShift);
}

public int[][] tetro()
{
    return tetro;
}

/**
 * makes the shadow of the tetris
 */
private void setShadTetro()
{
    while(checkCollision(shadTetro))    
        for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
            shadTetro[i][1]++;

    myBoard.setTetris(shadTetro, color+7, xShift, yShift);
}

/**
 * A replica of the tetris constructor
 * Helps to simply redefine all the values
 * since creating multiple tetris objects is unneccessary
 */
public void newTetris()
{
    color = temColor;
    tetro = temTetro;

    for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
            shadTetro[i][j]=tetro[i][j];
    setShadTetro();

    myBoard.setTetris(temTetro, 0, xPos, yPos);

    temColor = (int)(Math.random()*7)+1;
    temTetro = chooseRandom(temColor);

    myBoard.setTetris(temTetro, temColor, xPos, yPos);
    myBoard.setTetris(tetro, color, xShift, yShift);
}

/**
 * chooses a tetromino based on the random number inserted
 * @param c
 * @return the desired tetromino
 */
private static int[][] chooseRandom(int c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
    case 1:
        return new int[][] {{-1,0},{0,0},{1,0},{1,1}};//J
    case 2:
        return new int[][] {{-1,1},{0,0},{-1,0},{1,0}};//L
    case 3:
        return new int[][] {{-1,0},{0,0},{1,0},{2,0}};//I
    case 4:
        return new int[][] {{-1,0},{0,0},{0,1},{1,1}};//Z
    case 5:
        return new int[][] {{-1,1},{0,0},{0,1},{1,0}};//S
    case 6:
        return new int[][] {{1,0},{0,0},{1,1},{0,1}};//O
    case 7:
        return new int[][] {{-1,0},{0,0},{1,0},{0,1}};//T
    }

    return new int[1][1];
}

/**
 * Checks for floor collision
 * @param tet
 * @return true, if collided
 * @return false, if not
 */
public boolean checkCollision(int[][] tet)
{
    for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        if(tet[i][1]+1>19)
        {
            //System.out.println("1");
            return false;
        }
        if(tet.equals(tetro))
        {
            int val = myBoard.getValue(tet[i][0]+xShift , tet[i][1]+1);
            if(val>0 && val<8 && !contains(tet, tet[i][0], tet[i][1]+1))
            {
                //System.out.println("2");
                return false;
            }
        }

        else if(myBoard.getValue(tet[i][0]+xShift, tet[i][1]+1)!=0 && !contains(tet, tet[i][0], tet[i][1]+1))
        {
            //System.out.println("3");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * checks to see if the inputed coordinates are part of the tetromino or not
 * @param tet
 * @param r
 * @param c
 * @return true, if tetromino contains those coordinates
 * @return false, if not
 */
private static boolean contains(int[][] tet, int r, int c)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        if(r==tet[i][0] && c==tet[i][1])
            return true;

    return false;
}

/**
 * checks for wall collision
 * @param direction
 * @return true, if collided
 */
public boolean checkWall(int d)
{
    if(d>0)
        for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
        {
            if(tetro[i][0]>4)
                return false;
            int val = myBoard.getValue(tetro[i][0]+xShift+1, tetro[i][1]);
            if(val>0 && val<8 && !contains(tetro, tetro[i][0]+1, tetro[i][1]))
                return false;
        }

    else
        for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
        {
            if(tetro[i][0]<-3)
                return false;
            int val = myBoard.getValue(tetro[i][0]+xShift-1, tetro[i][1]);
            if(val>0 && val <8 && !contains(tetro, tetro[i][0]-1, tetro[i][1]))
                return false;
        }

    return true;
}

/**
 * makes the tetromino fall one step
 */
public void fall()
{
    myBoard.setTetris(tetro, 0, xShift, yShift);

    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        tetro[i][1]++;

    myBoard.setTetris(tetro, color, xShift, yShift);
}

/**
 * moves the tetromino left or right
 * @param dir
 */
public void move(int dir)
{
    myBoard.setTetris(tetro, 0, xShift, yShift);

    if(dir>0)
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
            //if(tetro[i][0]<5)
                tetro[i][0]++;
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
            // if(tetro[i][0]>-3)
                tetro[i][0]--;
    }

    myBoard.setTetris(shadTetro, 0, xShift, yShift);

    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        for(int j=0 ; j<2 ; j++)
            shadTetro[i][j] = tetro[i][j];
    setShadTetro();

    myBoard.setTetris(tetro, color, xShift, yShift);
    myBoard.repaint();
}

/**
 * rotates the tetromino
 */
public void rotateTetro()
{
    if(color==6) return;
    alt++;  // this "alt" field let's pieces 's', 'z', and 'i' alternate between clockwise and counter-clockwise,
            // since these pieces would shift left/right otherwise.

    myBoard.setTetris(tetro, 0, xShift, yShift);
    myBoard.setTetris(shadTetro, 0,xShift, yShift);

    switch(checkRotation())
    {
    case 0:
        for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
            tetro[i][0]--;

        if(color==3)
            for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
                tetro[i][0]--;
        break;

    case 1:
        for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
            tetro[i][0]++;
        break;

    case 2:
        for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
            tetro[i][1]--;
        break;

    case 3:
        for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
            tetro[i][1]++;

        if(color==3)
            for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
                tetro[i][1]++;

        break;

    case 4:
        myBoard.setTetris(tetro, color, xShift, yShift);
        return;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
        tetro[i] = rotPointOffset(tetro[i][0],tetro[i][1],tetro[1][0],tetro[1][1]);

    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        for(int j=0 ; j<2 ; j++)
            shadTetro[i][j] = tetro[i][j];
    setShadTetro();

    myBoard.setTetris(tetro, color,xShift, yShift);
    myBoard.repaint();
}

/**
 * checks to see if rotating causes it to go through the walls or into other pieces
 * @return type of collision
 */
public static int checkRotation()
{
    int[]tet;

    for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        tet= rotPointOffset(tetro[i][0],tetro[i][1],tetro[1][0],tetro[1][1]);
        if(tet[0]>5)
            return 0;
        if(tet[0]<-xShift)
            return 1;
        if(tet[1]>19)
            return 2;
        if(tet[1]<0)
            return 3;
        if(myBoard.getValue(tet[0]+xShift, tet[1])!=0 && !contains(tetro, tet[0], tet[1]))
            return 4;
    }

    return 5;
}

/**
 * rotates coordinate (x,y) about (a,b)
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 */
public static int[] rotPointOffset(int x, int y, int a, int b)
{
    if(color==7 || color==1 || color==2)
        return new int[] {y-b+a,a-x+b};

    else
    {
        if(alt%2==0)
            return new int[] {y-b+a,a-x+b};
        else
            return new int[] {b-y+a,x-a+b};
    }
}
}
```

---

Now don't get carried away with all the methods and what not. My question relates to the TetrisGame constructor, where I created the two Tetris objects : tetromino and tet2. When I first create tet2, it has it's own tetris piece (which is just an array). However, upon creating tetromino in the next line, the tetris piece (as well as all other fields) of the tet2 object is changed.

Now, I assessed the situation. Basically, these two objects that I've created are only accessors of the Tetris class, and for some reason, don't have their own unique set of field values like I expected them to. I've also confirmed that their memory locations are separate, using the toString() method. I've made multiplayer games before, using this same technique, but for some reason this isn't working. I would be obliged by any suggestions. Thanks you.

Also, for all you enthusiasts who want to try this out on your computer, here's the board2 class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class board2 extends JPanel
{
private int[][] mtx;
private int ver , hor;
private int sz;

//private int[][] nextTet;
//private int nextCol;
private int score;

private Color color;//, nexColor;
private boolean end;

public board2(int r, int c)
{
    hor = r; ver = c;
    sz=30;
    mtx=new int[c][r+16];

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension((hor+16)*sz,ver*sz+15));
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    repaint();
}

public boolean checkRow(int r)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
        if(mtx[r][i]==0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

public void removeRow(int r) throws InterruptedException
{
    for(int i=r ; i>=0 ; i--)
        for(int j=0 ; j<10 ; j++)
            if(i>0)
                mtx[i][j]=mtx  [i-1][j];
            else
                mtx[i][j]=0;

    //mtx[0]=new int[26];
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(300, 0, 300, 600);
    g.drawLine(306, 0, 306, 580);
    g.drawLine(26, 580, 306, 580);
    for(int i=0 ; i<ver ; i++)
        g.drawLine(306, i*28+20, 300, i*sz);
    g.drawLine(0, 600, 300, 600);
    for(int i=0 ; i<hor+1 ; i++)
        g.drawLine(i*sz, 600, i*28+26, 580);

    for(int i=ver-1 ; i>9 ; i--)
        for(int j=hor+15 ; j>12 ; j--)
        {
            setColor(mtx[i][j]);
            if(mtx[i][j]>0)
            {
                //for(int k=0 ; k<26 ; k++)
                //{
                    g.setColor(color.darker().darker());
                    //g.drawLine(j*sz+k, i*sz+k, (j+1)*sz+k, i*sz+k);
                    g.fillPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz, j*28+26, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+28+20, i*28+20}, 4);
                    g.setColor(color.darker());
                    g.fillPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz, i*28+20, i*28+20}, 4);

                    //g.drawLine(j*sz+k, i*sz+k, j*sz+k, (i+1)*sz+k);
                //}
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);
                if(mtx[i][j]<8)
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

                g.drawRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz, j*28+26, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+28+20, i*28+20}, 4);
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz, i*28+20, i*28+20}, 4);
                //g.fillPolygon(new int[] {j*sz+15, j*sz+45, j*sz+15, j*sz+45}, new int[] {i*sz+15, i*sz+15, i*sz+45, i*sz+45}, 4);

            }
            //g.drawRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);

        }

    for(int i=ver-1 ; i>9 ; i--)
        for(int j=0 ; j<13 ; j++)
        {
            setColor(mtx[i][j]);
            if(mtx[i][j]>0)
            {
                //for(int k=0 ; k<26 ; k++)
                //{
                g.setColor(color.darker().darker());
                // g.drawLine(j*sz+k, i*sz+k, (j+1)*sz+k, i*sz+k);
                g.fillPolygon(new int[] { j * sz + sz, j * sz + sz, j * 28 + 26 + 28, j * 28 + 26 + 28 },
                        new int[] { i * sz, i * sz + sz, i * 28 + 28 + 20, i * 28 + 20 }, 4);
                g.setColor(color.darker());
                g.fillPolygon(new int[] { j * sz, j * sz + sz, j * 28 + 26 + 28, j * 28 + 26 },
                        new int[] { i * sz, i * sz, i * 28 + 20, i * 28 + 20 }, 4);

                    //g.drawLine(j*sz+k, i*sz+k, j*sz+k, (i+1)*sz+k);
                //}
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);
                if(mtx[i][j]<8)
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

                g.drawRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {j*sz+sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26+28}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+28+20, i*28+20}, 4);
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz, i*28+20, i*28+20}, 4);

            }
            //g.drawRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);

        }
    for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
        for(int j=hor+15 ; j>12 ; j--)
        {
            setColor(mtx[i][j]);
            if(mtx[i][j]>0)
            {
                //for(int k=0 ; k<26 ; k++)
                // {
                g.setColor(color.darker());
                g.fillPolygon(new int[] { j * sz, j * sz + sz, j * 28 + 26 + 28, j * 28 + 26 },
                        new int[] { i * sz+sz, i * sz+sz, i * 28 + 28+20, i * 28 + 28 +20 }, 4);
                g.setColor(color.darker().darker());
                // g.drawLine(j*sz+k, i*sz+k, (j+1)*sz+k, i*sz+k);
                g.fillPolygon(new int[] { j * sz, j * sz, j * 28 + 26, j * 28 + 26 },
                        new int[] { i * sz, i * sz + sz, i * 28 + 28 + 20, i * 28 + 20 }, 4);

                // g.drawLine(j*sz+k, i*sz+k, j*sz+k, (i+1)*sz+k);
                // }
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);
                if(mtx[i][j]<8)
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

                g.drawRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz, j*28+26, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+28+20, i*28+20}, 4);
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz+sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+28+20, i*28+28+20}, 4);
            }
            //g.drawRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);

        }
    for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
        for(int j=0 ; j<13 ; j++)
        {
            setColor(mtx[i][j]);
            if(mtx[i][j]>0)
            {
                //for(int k=0 ; k<26 ; k++)
                //{
                    g.setColor(color.darker().darker());
                    //g.drawLine(j*sz+k, i*sz+k, (j+1)*sz+k, i*sz+k);
                    g.fillPolygon(new int[] {j*sz+sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26+28}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+28+20, i*28+20}, 4);
                    g.setColor(color.darker());
                    g.fillPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz+sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+20+28, i*28+20+28}, 4);

                    //g.drawLine(j*sz+k, i*sz+k, j*sz+k, (i+1)*sz+k);
                //}
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);
                if(mtx[i][j]<8)
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

                g.drawRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {j*sz+sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26+28}, new int[] {i*sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+28+20, i*28+20}, 4);
                g.drawPolygon(new int[] {j*sz, j*sz+sz, j*28+26+28, j*28+26}, new int[] {i*sz+sz, i*sz+sz, i*28+20+28, i*28+20+28}, 4);
                //g.fillPolygon(new int[] {j*sz+15, j*sz+45, j*sz+15, j*sz+45}, new int[] {i*sz+15, i*sz+15, i*sz+45, i*sz+45}, 4);

            }
            //g.drawRect(j*sz, i*sz, sz, sz);

        }


    Font font = new Font("Typo Round Regular Demo", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("NEXT:", (hor+1)*sz, 260);
    g.setFont(font.deriveFont(30f));

    g.drawString("SCORE:"+score, 345, 30);

    if(end)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(20, 225, 440, 160);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(20, 225, 440, 160);
        g.setFont(font.deriveFont(60f));
        g.drawString("GAME OVER", 63, 330);

    }

}

public int getValue(int r, int c)
{
    return mtx[c][r];
}

public void setTetris(int[][] tet, int c, int xShift, int yShift)
{

    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println((tet[i][0]+xShift)+","+(tet[i][1]+yShift));
        mtx[tet[i][1]+yShift][tet[i][0]+xShift]=c;}
    //System.out.println("\n\n");
}

public void sendNext(int[][] tetro, int color)
{
    for(int i=8; i<11 ; i++)
        for(int j=11; j<15 ; j++)
            mtx[i][j]=0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<4; i++)
        mtx[tetro[i][1]+9][tetro[i][0]+12]=color;
}

private void setColor(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
    case 1:
        color = Color.BLUE;
        break;
    case 2:
        color = new Color(255,128,0);
        break;
    case 3:
        color = Color.CYAN;
        break;
    case 4:
        color = Color.RED;
        break;
    case 5:
        color = new Color(128,255,0);
        break;
    case 6:
        color = Color.YELLOW;
        break;
    case 7:
        color = Color.MAGENTA;
        break;
    case 8:
        color = new Color(190,190,255);
        break;
    case 9:
        color = new Color(255,222,190);
        break;
    case 10:
        color = new Color(190,255,255);
        break;
    case 11:
        color = new Color(255,190,190);
        break;
    case 12:
        color = new Color(222,255,190);
        break;
    case 13:
        color = new Color(255,255,190);
        break;
    case 14:
        color = new Color(255,190,255);
    }
}

public void setEnd(boolean s)
{
    end =s;
}

public void setScore(int s)
{
    score = s;
}

}
```

---

I apologize for all the lines of codes that have been commented out. I should've trimmed them out!

Comment: There's way too much code here. Post a [mcve] demonstrating your specific problem. You might just solve it yourself while doing so.

Comment: @Rapid Readers Side note re: `public TetrisGame() throws InterruptedException` - A constructor should never throw `InterruptedException`. The first and most important memory barrier is at completion of initialization. You start messing with threads before then and you're asking for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of the static modifiers on your variables in the classes where you want more than one instance of that object. Static means that there will only be one value for a variable in a class, for example, it can be used to keep track of how many balls you have created from a ball class.

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.